# Finding a number of a line with a specific string in a file

Tags: c++, string, file, find, getline

I want my program to return number of line in which there is a specific string.
Whole line should be this string.

I don't know why it always returns a length of whole file.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <limits>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;


int main () {
int x;
x=0;
string filename, inputfilename, line;
ifstream inputfile;

while(!inputfile.is_open()) {
    cout << "Input filename: ";
    getline (cin, inputfilename);
    inputfile.open(inputfilename.c_str(),ios::in | ios::binary);
}

//string obj = "[I.LOVE.COOKIES]"; //Was like this
string obj = "[I.LOVE.COOKIES]\r"; //Adding \r solved the problem
while(getline(inputfile, line))
{
    if(line==obj)
    {
        return x;
    }
    else
    {
        x++;
    }

}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because the file does not contain the search string, and the shown code exhibits undefined behavior in that case, by returning from `main()` without a value. Furthermore, this program will only handle very small files properly, since the return code from a program is limited to 7 bits only. In other words: scrap this whole thing, and rewrite it from scratch.

Comment: I'd drop ios::binary if you're reading text...

Comment: @SamVarshavchik why is returning from main without a value UB ?

Comment: I forgot to copy return 0 at the end, but its not a case because in the file there have to be this string.

Comment: Please add example text from the file you are reading and the file encoding.

Comment: When a comparison does not work as expected, it is often interesting to dump the content of a line... Just do it and the reason will become evident. This should be enough: `while(getline(inputfile, line)) { std::cout << ">" << line << "<" << std::endl; ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to omit `ios::binary` as argument when opening the file.

The problem is that on windows, a line ends with the two characters `\r\n`. If you open the file in binary mode, `std::getline` will read a line and include the carriage return `\r`. This means that your string comparison fails, because the string `"[I.LOVE.COOKIES]"` does not end with `\r`.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Adding \r at the end of the string solved the problem.
string obj = "[I.LOVE.COOKIES]\r";

Comment: @Ziemni [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)